# solve HttpClient erro in angular 9

Tags: angular

I want to insert some user details to my database. Currently I am working in Angular 9. I think all i am done good but Currently I am facing some error in Importing Http. Why this error I am getting??As there I have tried some similar questions but I didn't got my answer.

**what I have tried**

**my service file**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {HttpClient} from '@angular/common/http';
import {observable, Observable}  from 'rxjs';
import {Signup} from './signup';
import { from } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SignupserviceService {
  createsignup(signup: Signup):Observable<Signup> {
    throw new Error("Method not implemented.");
    return this.http.post<Signup>(this.url+'api/users',signup)
    
  }
  url="http://localhost:51180/";

  constructor(private http:HttpClient) { }

  createuser(user:Signup):Observable<Signup>
  {
     return this.http.post<Signup>(this.url+'api/users',user)
  }
}
```

**my signup.component.ts file**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {FormBuilder,Validators,FormGroup} from '@angular/forms';
import {SignupserviceService} from '../signup/signupservice.service';
import {Signup} from '../signup/signup';
import { from } from 'rxjs';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-signup',
  templateUrl: './signup.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./signup.component.css']
})
export class SignupComponent implements OnInit {
  navbarOpen = false;
  regForm: FormGroup;
  datasaved:boolean= false;
  massage: string;

  toggleNavbar() {
    this.navbarOpen = !this.navbarOpen;
  }

  constructor(private formbuilder: FormBuilder, private signupservice:SignupserviceService
    ) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }




  setFormState(): void {
    this.regForm = this.formbuilder.group({
      email: ['', [Validators.required]],
      password: ['', [Validators.required]]
    })
  }

  onSubmit() {
    
    let signup = this.regForm.value;

    this.createsignup(signup);
    this.regForm.reset();
  }

  createsignup(signup: Signup) {
    this.signupservice.createsignup(signup).subscribe(
      () => {
        this.datasaved = true;
        this.massage = "User Created";
       this.regForm.reset();
      }
    )
  }

}
```

**the error I have got**

```
ERROR in node_modules/@angular/common/http/http.d.ts:81:22 - error NG6002: Appears in the NgModule.imports of AppModule, but could not be resolved to an NgModule class.

This likely means that the library (@angular/common/http) which declares HttpClient has not been processed correctly by ngcc, or is not compatible with Angular 
Ivy. Check if a newer version of the library is available, and update if so. Also consider checking with the library's authors to see if the library is expected to be compatible with Ivy.

81 export declare class HttpClient {
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "name": "localpost",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/common": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/compiler": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/core": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/forms": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.0.6",
    "@angular/router": "~10.0.6",
    "@icon/icofont": "^1.0.1-alpha.1",
    "angular-font-awesome": "^3.1.2",
    "aos": "^2.3.4",
    "boxicons": "^2.0.5",
    "counterup2": "^1.0.4",
    "countup.js": "^2.0.6",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^5.6.1",
    "ngx-owl-carousel-o": "^4.0.0",
    "remixicon": "^2.5.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.5",
    "tslib": "^2.0.0",
    "waypoints": "^4.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1000.5",
    "@angular/cli": "~10.0.5",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.0.6",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "codelyzer": "^6.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0",
    "karma": "~5.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~3.3.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.9.5"
  }
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { BodyComponent } from './component/body/body.component';
import { FooterComponent } from './component/footer/footer.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './component/login/login.component';
import { SignupComponent } from './component/signup/signup.component';
import { SignupserviceService } from './component/signup/signupservice.service';
import { HttpClientModule, HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';



@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    BodyComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    SignupComponent,
    
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    HttpClient
  ],
  providers: [SignupserviceService],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Please help why this error I am getting

Thank you

Comment: can you post your package.json please?

Comment: are you upgrading the older version side by side?

Comment: @SwarupChavan: no upgrading...i have strated learning angular...and this is my first project

Comment: Check your app.module.ts file and see if you have imported HttpClientModule @Nehasingh or if you can post it here that would be great

Comment: @SwarupChavan: Yes i have edited the question .. i have added ```app.module.ts``` file

Comment: @Nehasingh you also have to specify it inside the import of @ NgModule

Comment: @SwarupChavan: After putting into ngModule There are lot of error occurs. see this> [error](https://paste.pics/a02efa4d230e6d7095e92ec0ef798ed8) ...........second ly after removing ```httpClient``` doesn't works.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220305/discussion-between-neha-singh-and-swarup-chavan).

Answer (score 1):

check your imports in ngModule ,that should fix it

```
imports: [  
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
```

and if you are using injectables,there wont be need to provide your service for injection in the @ngmodule,you can choose either one of them

Comment:  yous answer is totally  correct but you may need to add extra information ,so he will get the idea why he face a problem

Answer (score 0):

you have a problem in app.module , you have add `HttpClient` to the import list and this was invalid that why you get this error , when you import HttpClientModule you will be able to inject the HttpClinet object in any service

```js
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule, // in case you use angular reactive forms 
    HttpClient // <-- remove this line 
  ],
```

Comment: I have got error in ```[formGroup]="regForm"````. and many more errors

Comment: that is different error you  need to import  `ReactiveFormsModule`